Show $E[Y | E[Y | X]] = E[Y | X]$.
Given Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables on a common probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$.
To show: $E[Y | E[Y | X]] = E[Y | X]$
For this problem, I'm unsure how to rewrite the left-hand side of the statement since I don't know how to deal with a conditional expectation as a condition in another conditional expectation; any initial hints would be appreciated.

Check out https://www.math.arizona.edu/~tgk/464_07/cond_exp.pdf

Is this question treated in there? I don't see it

It is a direct application of the identity: $E[Y\mid f(X)]=E\big[E[Y\mid X]\mid f(X)\big]$.

@DagunDagun gave great hints. I will write it out more explicitly for my own benefit.
Let $\sigma(X)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variable $X$. It would suffice to show $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ is $\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right)$-measurable and
$$\int_A \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \ \text{d}\mathbb{P} = \int_A Y \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}$$
for all $A \in \sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right)$. We know $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ is $\sigma\left( X \right)$-measurable and
$$\int_A \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \ \text{d}\mathbb{P} = \int_A Y \ \text{d}\mathbb{P}$$
for all $A \in \sigma\left( X \right)$. Therefore it would suffice to show
$$\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right) \subseteq \sigma\left( X \right)$$
Recall $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable and $\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right)$ is the smallest  $\sigma$-algebra that makes $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ measurable. We conclude $\sigma\left( \mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right] \right) \subseteq \sigma\left( X \right)$.

The part that $\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right]$ is $\sigma(\mathbb{E}\left[ Y \mid X \right])$-measurable is trivial. Nothing to show. The rest is a very good answer.

You should be done using the definition of the conditional expectation.
To be more precise, recall that on a probability space $(\Omega, \cal F, \mathbb{P})$, given a random variable $X$ and a $\sigma-$algebra $\cal G\subset\cal F$, $\mathbb{E}\left[X|\cal G\right]$ is the unique random variable $Z$ that verifies :

$Z$ is integrable,
$Z$ is $\cal G-$measurable,
$\mathbb{E}[Z\mathbb{1}_G] = \mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{1}_G]$ for any $G\in\cal G$.

Recall also that if $Y$ is another random variable, then by definition $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=\mathbb{E}[X|\sigma(Y)]$.
Let me know if you need any more help.

In other words, check if the RHS satisfies the definition of the LHS.
